# EsriSecurityException while Utilizing Client's Map services

Tags: android, arcgis

Working on an Android app which utilizes ArcGIS Android SDK. In the project, I am having a requirement where in I need to show some maps of our client. Those services are all secured and can be accessed only via VPN. The VPN server type is Juniper for which I had installed Junos Pulse app in my phone. Made the VPN connection in Junos Pulse app. Trying to make a ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer instance by passing the URL of my client's map service. But it's giving me EsriSecurityException.

Would like to know is my app not able to recognize the VPN connection made in Junos Pulse app? Other than providing the credentials (while making the VPN connection) do I still have to pass the credentials by my app as well? If yes, in what format?

Can somebody please guide on how can I utilize some secured Map Services of a particular domain?

Thanks.

Comment: It's your right to put -ve vote for the question in case you didn't liked the question. But on the same time, you should have explained what are those "obvious reasons" due to which this question deserved -ve ranking.

Comment: Can you connect to the map service URL in a browser on the device? If not, then your app won't be able to do it either. Try it in a browser on the device and see what happens. It might give you some clues, which you could share with us by editing your question.

Comment: Thanks for providing the suggestion. Tried opening the URL in phone browser and yes, it's NOT working, even after connecting to VPN. Error message is "Web page isn't available".

Comment: Fix your VPN connection. That's your problem, not your app. Can your browser load a plain unsecured non-ArcGIS page inside your VPN network?

Comment: No, the browser isn't loading any unsecured non ArcGIS page after connecting to VPN. Checked to load stackoverflow.com and everytime it says connection_time_out.

Answer (score 0):

Get your VPN connection working and your ArcGIS services will work. This is a problem with Junos Pulse, not with ArcGIS.